# ANDROID HUAWEI device -> cannot get photo URI

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, photo

im taking photo by using this method:

```
 public void takePhoto () {
        try {
            Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "Trying to take photo");
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }

        }   catch (Exception e) {       
            Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "takePhoto method cannot be processed", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

On some devices i got always in onActivity result in image URI null (especially on Huawei devices).

I tried to find any working solution, but without luck.

Could please somebody tell me, how to solve this issue?

**Here is onActivityResultMethod:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "Trying to process image");
            GlobalApplication globalAppClass = ((GlobalApplication) getApplicationContext());
            AppHelper helper = new AppHelper();
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            if(imageUri == null) {
                Log.i(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "Image URI is null");
            }
            Bitmap bitmap;
            Bitmap resizedBitmap;
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "DAMAGE_" + globalAppClass.getEanCode() + "_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
            String dirname =  "smartt/"+globalAppClass.getEanCode();

            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
            resizedBitmap = helper.getResizedBitmap(bitmap, 768, 1024);
            helper.createDirectoryAndSaveImage(resizedBitmap, imageFileName, dirname);
            // place thumbnail into image view
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

            TextView photoCountTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.damageReportTakenPhotosCountTv);
            photoCountTv.setText(R.string.foto_attached);
            photoCountTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

            TextView dataPassingTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.damageReportPassingTitle);
            dataPassingTv.setText(R.string.data_passing);
            dataPassingTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "onActivityResult method cannot be processed, file not found", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "onActivityResult method cannot be processed, IOE Exception", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE, "onActivityResult method cannot be processed, Exception", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Try supplying your own output location using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`.

Comment: I would like to save photo in internal storage. I dont need URI, bitmap (but no thumbnail) should be o.k. But i don't know, how to get it.

Comment: "I would like to save photo in internal storage" -- a third-party camera app cannot directly save the photo in your app's internal storage. The code you have above will save the photo in external storage, probably in the standard directory for photos, or wherever that camera app elects to store them. Your choices will either be to supply your own location on external storage and then move the photo to your app's internal storage, or to use the `Camera` yourself to take a picture rather than rely upon a third-party app.

Answer (score 0):

i know this question is older, but i think many people have a problem with that. As @CommonsWare stated out you have to provide your own URI like this:

```
        photoFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            String fileName = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
             startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
```

with a file like this:

```
    public File getOutputMediaFile() {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "Shaufel");
    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            // base.saveValidationError("MyCameraApp: failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp
            + ".jpg");
    return mediaFile;
}
```

just safe in your application the fileName (perhaps also onSaveInstanceState())

in onActivityResult i load the bitmap like this

```
        public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, File file, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream ino = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(ino.getFD(), null, options);
        ino.close();

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        this.reqHeight = reqHeight;
        this.reqWidth = reqWidth;
        // Raw height and width of image
        this.height = options.outHeight;
        this.width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power
            // of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and
            // width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    || (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```